# How can I import cordova-android respository to platform of cordova-base project from svn

Tags: android, cordova, svn, npm

I downloaded a cordova-android respository from github,and it's a git-respository.
Then I uploaded this respository to svn,and I only modified some config of `package.json` file for this svn-respository, as `"respository"` label, I modified its inner label `"type":"git"` to `"type":"svn"`.When I used order `platform add http://my/svn/site/cordova-android` in CLI, It throws me some errors.

```
Error: Failed to fetch platform http://my/svn/site/cordova-android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 254 Error output:
npm ERR! not a package /var/folders/qs/nvr1v1ts6vjgk9sfxdrn92xm0000gn/T/npm-99652-2758af32/my/svn/site/cordova-android

npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "http:///my/svn/site/cordova-android" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! path /var/folders/qs/nvr1v1ts6vjgk9sfxdrn92xm0000gn/T/npm-99652-2758af32/unpack-3bf64aae/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/qs/nvr1v1ts6vjgk9sfxdrn92xm0000gn/T/npm-99652-2758af32/unpack-3bf64aae/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/qs/nvr1v1ts6vjgk9sfxdrn92xm0000gn/T/npm-99652-2758af32/unpack-3bf64aae/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/xb/.npm/_logs/2017-07-27T02_15_59_655Z-debug.log
```

Who can give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Users\mypc.cordova\lib\npm_cache, find cordova-android folder.

do changes whatever you did in svn.

then run command 'cordova platform add android'

Comment: Which seems it's a promising solution, could you give me correct directory when I use Mac OS? thanks.